# ExoPlayer Error: cannot find symbol variable CRYPTO_MODE_AES_CBC

Tags: android, cryptography, exoplayer

Cloned the Android ExoPlayer project from github (https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)
and opened in Android Studio.

Getting this error: `cannot find symbol variable CRYPTO_MODE_AES_CBC`

Any suggestions how to fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CRYPTO_MODE_AES_CBC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#CRYPTO_MODE_AES_CBC) was added in Android 7.0, API 24. Make sure you have API 24 installed and you are compiling with API 24 (which is [the default](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/build.gradle#L32)).

Comment: This pinpointed the problem. I had edited the ExoPlayer `build.gradle` file and set `compileSdkVersion=23` and `targetSdkVersion=23`, so that was part of the problem. I have now also downloaded and installed API 24, along with other recent updates, including Android Studio 2.2.1.